# Corner Radius for Hover Rectangle

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

How can I set something like corner radius for the default rectangle which appears when an item is hovered?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit non-specific, which is why people are down voting you.

If you're talking about a Flex Button; the rounded corners on roll-over are part of an FXG asset; which is not changed by use of the cornerRadius style.  At least in the mobile skin; I imagine the desktop skin is similar.

We put together a mobile skin that will [create a square button](https://www.flextras.com/MobileComponents/Docs/asdocs/com/flextras/mobile/shared/skins/ButtonSkinSquare.html); and something that should have been trivial took a few days.  It's available as part of the [Flextras Mobile Flex Components Package](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductDocumentation&ProductID=21) and usable for free.

Here is a [sample](https://www.flextras.com/MobileComponents/Samples/SquareButtonSample/) we put together to show the button differences.

You can use in a non-mobile project at your own risk, though.

Answer (score 0):

Trival in Flex3.
You did not specify what you are styling so this is how I would style a button

```
<mx:Style>
  .roundedbtn{
    cornerRadius: 10;
  }
</mx:Style>

<mx:Button id='btn' styleName='mybtnnormal />

// or in ActionScript
btn.styleName = 'roundedbtn';

// or without the styles
<mx:Button cornerRadius="10" />
```